# Proof that the sequence $x_n=f_{n+1}/f_n$ convergences to the golden ration $\Phi$

Tags: sequences-and-series, fibonacci-numbers, golden-ratio

I'm supposed to proof that the sequence $x_n:=f_{n+1}/f_n,n\in\mathbb{N}$ converges to the golden ratio $\Phi$ where $f_n:=f_{n-1}+f_{n-2}$ is the Fibonacci sequence with $f_1=1$ and $f_2=1$. At first I needed to show that

\begin{align*}
|\Phi-x_n|&=\left|1+\frac{1}{\Phi}-\left(1+\frac{1}{x_{n-1}}\right)\right|\\
&=\left|\frac{1}{\Phi}-\frac{1}{x_{n-1}}\right|\\
&=\left|\frac{x_{n-1}-\Phi}{\Phi x_{n-1}}\right|
\end{align*}

but I'm stuck trying to show that $|\Phi-x_{n}|\leqslant|\Phi-x_2|/\Phi^{n-2}$. Can anyone please help me to solve this problem? Thanks in andvance!

Comment: Use $x_{n-1}>1$

Comment: Have a look at [this link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2569135/establishing-monotonicity-of-the-sequence-of-ratio-of-fibonacci-like-sequence/2570266) as well.